# How can I set the zoom point of a Google Map in iOS to be off-center?

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I am implementing a Google Maps for iOS SDK map in my app. I have a UISlider that controls the level of zoom in the map. I want to be able to have the map zoom in on a point that is not directly in the center of the map -- and after zooming in, this point should be offset from the center of the map by the same number of pixels as before.

I tried setting mapView.layer.anchorPoint to an off-center point, but if I do that, then it screws up the map drawing and it draws the whole map off-center, leaving black areas.

I tried zooming in on the point itself, but that moves it to the center of the map, which I don't want.

Is there a convenience method for simply telling the SDK to treat a different point other than the direct center, as being the "fulcrum", if you will, of the zooming?